# what is the correct file path format in windows enviorment?

Tags: python, windows, selenium, github-actions

Recently, I used selenium to download file from online on Github Action(windows enviroment).

It's working, because I can locate the file I downloaded by:

```
# this helps me to locate the file_path&name I just downloaded.
file = [file[i] for i, x in enumerate(file) if x.find(str(next_date)) != -1]
file = [file[i] for i, x in enumerate(file) if x.find('csv') != -1][0]
```

However, I can't read it by:

```
pd.read_csv(file)
```

it got error

```
No such file or directory: 'C:\\202204_10エリア計.csv'
```

after I search on the internet, i changed the double backslash to single forwardslash,
but the problem still exists:

```
No such file or directory: 'C:/202204_10エリア計.csv'
```

P.S.
double backslash works fine on my windows PC, it's just not working on Github Action(windows enviroment)

Comment: Just a guess but if the filename contains non-latin characters then you may be encountering an encoding problem. You can prove this by downloading the file to a simple name like "test.csv" and if that works then you know there's a character encoding problem somewhere.

Comment: @Andy Brown u were right, after i test it with english filename, it works fine. So, I think right now I need to find a way to rename the filename to english, instead of japanese

Comment: You could try setting the environment variable `PYTHONUTF8=1` _before_ the python interpreter is launched (e.g. in your launch configuration for github actions?) It might solve the issue.

Comment: yea, thanks to your advice, i added #!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- at the top of code, and somehow it works:)

Comment: @KowComical I'm trying to do the same thing, but can't find the file anywhere. How did you setup your driver options? I can't tell if the issue is with my download_directory

Comment: @mmille it worked when i set chrome option download path by 'prefs = {"download.default_directory": file_path}'

Comment: @KowComical thanks for responding! sorry, but what did you actually set as your file_path? I saw this was my working directory, so I tried it but it didn't work - "D:\\a\\ariba\\ariba"

Comment: @mmille yea, it wasnt working on my end as well, i dont know why. However, I know the default download path for windows enviorment is somewhere called 'C://downloads', so, I found a solution that after download, i searched every file in 'C://downloads' for the key word '202204' (the first filename of my file), and got it, and then i output it on the github server

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you use a single backslash in Windows.

For example:  `C:\202204_10エリア計.csv`

Network paths are accessed with a double backslash.

For example: `\\host.domain\fileshare\202204_10エリア計.csv`

I heard a Linux guy say 'Windows is backwards' as a means of memorizing the way it works in Windows compared to *Nix.

Comment: emm, i tried with '//', '/', and '\', all failed, after i test it, i think the problem is from my filename

Comment: @KowComical Yeah, it could be because of the Japanese characters. Did you one with purely C:\202204_10.csv for example?

Comment: yea, it is because of the japanese characters, but thanks to @Andy Brown I finally read it correctly. Anyway, thanks for your help too:)